# AWS C# Lambda Returns Empty Array For Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, .net-6.0

I'm trying to POST a json object through postman and trying to get my lambda function to read it. Instead of returning the property value, it's returning an empty array.

Below is my simple lambda code.

```
using Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace LambdaS3FileUpload;

public class Function
{
    // public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request)
    public Object FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request)
    {
        var req = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(request.Body);
        return req;
    }
}
```

Below is my curl request.

```bash
curl --location 'https://uniqueid.lambda-url.ap-southeast-2.on.aws/' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"field_one":1, "field_two":2}'
```

Instead of setting 1 and 2 respectively for each field, I just get an empty array.

```json
{"field_two":[],"field_one":[]}
```

All I'm trying to do is access the POSTed data.
Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: In order to see if the data is in the Body, you can log out the entire request and check the logs. Since you are getting the field_one and field_two properties, it could be an issue with the serialization. The LambdaSerializer will do its best, but sometimes it's not what you would expect. You could try wrapping your data in either a string, like "field_one":"1", or in an array, like "field_one":[1], since it seems to be expecting an array there.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be returning `Object` from your Lambda - somehow this is internally messing up the response. You'd have to ask the Lambda team about what's exactly happening.

You should ideally be returning a defined response object like `APIGatewayProxyResponse`, or as a quick hack, return the body as it is:

```cs
using System;
using Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace LambdaTest;

public class Function
{
    public Object FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request)
    {
        string req = request.Body;
        return req;
    }
}
```

```bash
curl --location 'https://xxx.lambda-url.eu-west-2.on.aws/' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"field_one":1, "field_two":2}'
```

```json
{"field_one":1, "field_two":2}
```